# Recursive searching for dict keys in same dict values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion

I understand recursion pretty good I think, but in this case I ran out of ideas.
So basically we have a dict as below:

```
{
    'Key_1': 'Hello world',
    'Key_2': 'One',
    'Key_3': 'Bar Key_1',
    'Key_4': 'Foo Key_3 foo',
    'Key_5': 'Baz Key_1'
}
```

Each of dict keys can appear as a substring inside another key's value.
What I want to obtain is to get another dict, where the keys will remain, but the values will be adresses of where such key appears under another key's values. So basically the result I want to get is:

```
{
    'Key_1': ['Key_3', 'Key_4', 'Key_5'],
    'Key_2': [],
    'Key_3': ['Key_1'],
    'Key_4': ['Key_3', 'Key_1'],
    'Key_5': ['Key_1']
}
```

So basically I want to find the lowest level (such as Key_1) and find all the higher levels which are using directly or indirectly (Key_4 is in the list because it uses Key_3, and Key_3 uses Key_1). If any of the keys is not used anywhere, just return an empty list (such as Key_2 case).
Also the keys are not ordered.

Is there really any way to solve this? Any kind of help is appreciated!
I'm not posting my code because it has gotten me nowhere.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. You should always post your code here, even if it has gotten you nowhere. First, it might be that a small modification would get it to work, and someone here might spot that. Second, it makes it feel less like you're asking other people to just write code for you. Third, then we know what's already been tried, so you're more likely to get useful replies.

Comment: I posted an answer, but the result I get is not the one you showed. I can't interpret your question in the way that gives the result you are showing. Please rephrase your question more clearly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the dict is not too big, a naive bruteforce solution can be written using dict comprehension and list comprehension:

```py
new_dict = { k: [j for j,v in old_dict.items() if k in v] for k in old_dict }

print(new_dict)
# {'Key_1': ['Key_3', 'Key_5'],
#  'Key_2': [],
#  'Key_3': ['Key_4'],
#  'Key_4': [],
#  'Key_5': []}
```